# How to notify recyclerview adapter changes when navigating from other app

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, androidx

Initialized RecyclerView on my activity

```
private RecyclerView listView;

private ListCardAdapter listCardAdapter;

private Subscription subscription;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    listView = findViewById(R.id.subscription_list);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);

    listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    listCardAdapter= new ListCardAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    listCardAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    listCardAdapter.setAdapter(subscriptionListCardAdapter);

    getPurchases(); //runs a service and sets subscription value and calls back onSkuDetails

}

@Override
public void onSkuDetails(List<SkuDetails> skuDetails) {

    removeProgressDialog();

    listCardAdapter.setData(subscription, skuDetails);

}

//ListCardAdapter 
public void setData(Subscription subscription, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

    this.subscription = subscription;

    this.skuDetailsList = skuDetailsList;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When the user selects a button on my activity, it will call a method and calls back `onSkuDetails`, then it will update the adapter's data then you will see the changes on the items list.

One of the button will start the `google play store app` and navigate to user's subscription page,user cancels subscription, when the user clicks back button until he gets back to the app it will call `onSkuDetails`, after that the recyclerview adapter doesn't trigger the `onBindViewHolder` that causing the item from not updating, this only occurs when navigating from other app(play store), but when I try to pull down from the screen(refresh), it will call the `onBindViewHolder` then the item list gets updated.

Comment: When navigating from another app, it is most likely to call onResume() of your fragment/activity. You can try to call whatever method you want by overriding onResime

Comment: I already tried to put listCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); on my onResume(); but still not updating.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Run the `notifyDataSetChanged()` onUIthread.

```
private void notifyAdapterDataSetChanged() {

        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                subscriptionListCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```